# What is the correct usage of the word "both" in this example?

Tags: word-usage

I have been provided with the following sentence by a native English speaker

`Successful coalitions carefully choose the brands that they think are the best fit for their programme both in terms of value and benefit to their customers.`

I am not a native English speaker so a bit hesitant to point out that the correct placement of the word "both" should be as below. Am I right?

`Successful coalitions carefully choose the brands that they think are the best fit for their programme in terms of both value and benefit to their customers.`

Answer (score 1):

It is good you didn't correct them as the sentence is correct.

> Successful coalitions carefully choose the brands that they think are
>   the best fit for their programme both in terms of value and benefit to
>   their customers.

now why is it correct?

I don't know it just is! Hopefully somebody will know

Comment: As per (the answer to this question)[https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377984/both-in-terms-of-or-in-terms-of-both], this is grammatically wrong. It is entirely possible that it is an acceptable way of speaking/writing.

Comment: this looks like splitting infinitives to me (i.e. not really cared about)